# Add profile image for Sitecore user

Tags: user-profile, account

Can we add profile images for the Sitecore user. When a user is created, I can only see the option to assign an icon from a preset list.

My project is a blogging site, where every blogger is a sitecore user. Their blog should show the user image and name.

Using Sitecore 8.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create custom profile properties for the profile in the core database. There you can even use Image field. From your code you can reach it and show on the page.

How to create custom property - [Link](https://www.google.hu/amp/s/briancaos.wordpress.com/2014/06/12/sitecore-users-custom-profile-properties/amp/?client=ms-unknown)

1. Go to **core** database and create your custom profile template like `/sitecore/templates/System/Security/MyCustomProfile`
2. Create your custom profile from this template here `/sitecore/system/Settings/Security/Profiles`
3. In **User Manager** you can change the user profile on the users
   [image]

Comment: Can you add more information here so that the answer is complete? As it is you can't really get the answer without going to the link, which makes this a link only answer.